# ¿Cómo de estrictos debemos ser al editar diferentes variedades del español?

Tags: discusión, idioma-español

He estado navegando StackOverflow en Español por una hora y me he fijado que bastantes preguntas contienen errores gramaticales (principalmente mala puntuación y tildes que faltan) y necesitan edición, lo cual no es un gran problema, pero también me he encontrado casos en los que el español utilizado es particular de ciertas regiones/países. ¿Cómo se deberían tratar esos casos?

**¿Hay alguna variedad de español/castellano que debamos seguir a la hora de hacer correcciones?** Por ejemplo, ¿debería editar "podés" y sustituirlo por "puedes"? ¿o cambiar "vos" por "tú" o "usted"? Supongo que no se debería editar una pregunta/respuesta sólo para hacer esos cambios, pero ¿si se van a hacer más cambios?

Comment: gente.. a ver.. informal, respetuoso y cada uno escribe como puede, como le sale. No hay ninguna mejora para el sitio definiendo este tipo de cosas.

Comment: @rnrneverdies No estoy de acuerdo. Está bien escribir de manera informal pero, en un sitio web donde lo único que se puede ver del usuario es lo que escribe, no se debe escribir "como le sale" a cada uno. El respeto comienza por escribir bien y de manera correcta.

Comment: Coincido contigo y considero que lo más importante a corregir es el uso de los símbolos en preguntas y respuesta ya que hay carencia mucha carencia de ello.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Gramaticales si, de estilo no.

No me gustaría ver todos mis "puedes" cambiados por "podés" ni viceversa.

Solo lo haría si la pregunta/respuesta no se entiende y después de la edición es más clara

Comment: +1. E, incluso si la pregunta no se entiende, la cambiaría para que se entendiese pero dejando "puedes" como "puedes" y "podés" como "podés" que ambos se entiende perféctamente seas de donde seas y se debe respetar al autor original.

Answer (score 7):

Los errores gramaticales sí deben ser corregidos. Se hace todo el tiempo en el sitio inglés. No por ser de habla hispana debemos tener menor calidad de escritura.

Answer (score 6):

En el chat de Area51 se discutió brevemente sobre el tema del tratamiento, y el consenso parecía ser que es mejor usar "tú" que "usted", ya que suena menos rígido y es el tratamiento usado habitualmente en la mayoría de sitios en los que hay personas interactuando.

Por lo demás, no hay por ahora ninguna regla "oficial" sobre el uso de las diversas variedades del idioma. A mí por ejemplo, como español "podés" me suena rarísimo, pero no voy a editar para cambiarlo por un "puedes" porque a un argentino (por ejemplo) le pasará lo mismo con dicho término.

Así pues, creo que mientras nos entendamos y no haya fallos ortográficos o gramaticales, no deberíamos darle demasiadas vueltas al asunto.

Comment: Considero que debe mencionarse que el contexto de la discusión en el chat de Area 51 acerca del tu/usted/vos era la traducción de elementos "fijos" como los artículos de la ayuda. En este caso se trata de la preguntas y respuestas :)

Comment: @Rubén aunque el enfoque va dirigido a otro tipo de artículos, creo que también debería aplicar para las preguntas y respuestas, la verdad le da un sentido cómodo a la conversación, algo como humano-humano.

Comment: @Chofoteddy en otra pregunta similar, la [respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/19/65) por [jachguate](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/users/21/jachguate) indica  que imponer reglas de estilo para las preguntas y respuestas sería contraproducente ya que implicaría una labor potencialmente excesiva dada la naturaleza abierta de los sitios de SE. Obviamente lo menciono porque estoy de acuerdo con ello.