# ¿Se deben usar siempre signos de interrogación en los títulos de las preguntas?

Tags: discusión, idioma-español

He publicado pocas preguntas en el SOes y en al menos en un par de ocasiones se han editado símplemente para colocar signos de interrogación en al inicio y final del enunciado del título.

Me parece que esto es un cambio que no agrega ningún valor.

Answer (score 7):

Ambas formas, con y sin signos, son válidas y se entienden igual de bien.

Pero eso sí: por favor no pongáis **sólo signo de cierre**, eso no es español válido y queda bastante feo. Poned los dos, apertura y cierre, o no pongáis ninguno.

Answer (score 3):

## Respuesta corta

El omitir los signos de interrogación en los títulos es válido. Es una cuestión de estilo, no se trata de un error gramatical.

## Explicación

De la referencia

> ### Signos de interrogación en títulos
>
> #### ¿Sería correcto escribir los siguientes títulos sin signos de interrogación: Qué deben hacer los padres, Qué es la menopausia?
>
> Los signos de interrogación se pueden omitir en los enunciados
> interrogativos independientes que se emplean como título de una obra,
> un capítulo o cualquier otra sección de un texto: Cómo escribir bien
> en español. También es posible conservar los signos de interrogación
> en estos casos: ¿Cómo escribir bien en español?

## Referencias

- [Signos de interrogación en títulos - Academia Mexicana de la Lengua](http://www.academia.org.mx/espin/Detalle?id=116)

## Discusiones en META SOes relacionadas

- [¿Cómo de estrictos debemos ser al editar diferentes variedades del español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/51/c%C3%B3mo-de-estrictos-debemos-ser-al-editar-diferentes-variedades-del-espa%C3%B1ol/)

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo +1. Y si tu lo prefieres sin signos de interrogación revierte las ediciones. Yo prefiero usar los signos de interrogación; pero es tu pregunta, es tu estilo. Seguro que quien hizo la edición lo hizo con buena intención; un comentario con enlace aquí debe ser suficiente.

Comment: En realidad, el título con signos de interrogación, y sin signos de interrogación, tiene un significado semántico diferente. Con signos de interrogación, es una pregunta. Sin signos, es simplemente un título. Al traducir a algunos idiomas, se nota esta diferencia. Como ejemplo, _What must parents do?_ vs _What Parents Must Do_, _How do/does I/one write correctly in Spanish?_ vs _How to Write Correctly in Spanish_, ...

Comment: @ninjalj: Gracias por unirte a la conversación. Por favor toma en cuenta que estamos hablando de SOes y la gramática del español. ¿Podrías incluir ejemplos en español?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: Coincido contigo en considerar que la intención de la edición era buena. Sobre colocar un enlace a esta discusión es algo que estoy dejando en espera mientras esta discusión recibe mayor atención.

Comment: Sin signos, _Qué deben hacer los padres_, tiene el significado de _Capítulo/Ensayo/lo que sea sobre lo que deben hacer los padres_. Es decir, introduce el tema correspondiente, en oposición a realiza la pregunta correspondiente, que es lo que haría la variante con signos de interrogación. Como anécdota, un estilo antiguo para los títulos incluye la preposición _sobre_ (ejemplo: _Sobre la vejez_, o en latín _De senectude_), con ese estilo, quedaría: _Sobre lo que deben hacer los padres_.

Answer (score 0):

Hablando de *edición*:

- Si es un usuario con privilegios de edición, en principio no, no hay ningún problema; es su prerrogativa y el sistema y los demás usuarios confiamos que lo hace porque cree que es necesario;
- Si es una sugerencia de edición, por definición es muy corta y no merece el tiempo de los revisores para su aprobación.

Sí hablamos de *estilo*, no lo sé e imagino que a Google le dá igual.

Comment: En la primera ocasión se trató de una una sugerencia de edición y recibí una notificación. En aquel momentos SOes estaba en BETA privada. En la segunda ocasión fue una edición de un usuario con privilegios de edición, no recibí notificación; me di cuenta de la edición al revisar las etiquetas. Entiendo que confiamos que lo hace un usuario con privilegios de edición porque cree que es necesario, sin embargo, en mi opinión no lo es. En cuanto a Búsqueda Web de Google, dicho servicio ignora los signos de interrogación.