# ¿Es correcto escribir preguntas dentro del cuerpo de la publicación?

Tags: discusión

Creo que algunas veces escribir lo que se quiere saber en el título de la publicación puede resultar complicado, por lo que en estos casos el título no lleva signos de interrogación y dentro del cuerpo están escritas una o más preguntas.

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Estás preguntando si el título de una pregunta puede no ser una pregunta? (-¡Más vale!) ... ¿O si una pregunta puede tener múltiples preguntas? (-No).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> El que los títulos sean en forma de pregunta no los hace ni buenos ni malos y el que que no tengan forma de pregunta, tampoco.

Me parece que estás considerando que por pregunta nos referimos a un enunciado, pero no, aquí nos referimos a un cuestionamiento en prosa<sup>1</sup> sobre temas de programación y otros asuntos relacionados en el que el título es un resumen del cuerpo del cuestionamiento. En el cuerpo es válido incluir varios enunciados en forma de pregunta pero siempre y cuando se refieran al mismo cuestionamiento, estos enunciados sería más preguntas retóricas que cuestionamientos distintos.

Nota: De acuerdo a la RAE, en los títulos es válido omitir los signos de interrogación de las preguntas.

> <sup>1</sup> A la fecha, no he visto ninguna pregunta en verso, ni en este sitio ni en inglés, pero no descarto que algún día haya alguna buena pregunta escrita así.

Artículo de ayuda relacionado

- [¿Cómo elaboro un buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Preguntas de Meta SOes relacionadas

- [¿Cuánto énfasis se debe hacer en editar el título de las preguntas, a fin de enriquecer el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1656/65)
- [¿Se deben usar siempre signos de interrogación en los títulos de las preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326/65)

Comment: Hay muchos títulos que no son un enunciado en forma de pregunta (2 mías, pero hay muchas más).

Comment: En otras palabras, el  que los títulos  sean en forma de pregunta no los hace ni buenos ni malos y el que que no tengan forma de pregunta, tampoco :D

Comment: Yo tampoco, pero siendo, meta, aquí podemos ser **aún más** laxos ;)