# ¿Qué es el consenso y cómo funciona?

Tags: discusión

Últimamente ha habido dos situaciones molestas, las cuales se colocan, curiosamente en extremos opuestos, tanto porque una fue planteada en Meta y la otra en Stackoverflow, así como porque una adoleció de *falta de consenso* y la otra fue sobrevolada por otra sin aplicar ningún tipo de *consenso*.

El **caso 1** fue el de una pregunta-respuesta planteada del otro lado, la cual fue cerrada, re-abierta y luego cerrada como demasiado amplia. Dicha pregunta, por cierto, fue modificada y adaptada a las *normas* , pero permanece cerrada. El asunto fue expuesto aquí en Meta: [¿Qué ocurre con la pregunta “Manejar conexiones a bases de datos MySQL mediante PDO: principios básicos”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2279/29967)

El **caso 2** fue el de una pregunta marcada como duplicada de otra más nueva. Quizá el término correcto sea *sobrevolada*. SO es incoherente también en el mensaje de cierre, porque dice que _su pregunta **ya fue planteada**, X tiempo después de haberla planteado usted. El asunto también fue planteado en Meta: [¿Cuál es el criterio que han seguido para marcar esta pregunta como duplicada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2377/29967)

El hecho es que en las discusiones de estos asuntos recientes (y en otras), he visto que se apela al *consenso*, lo cual entiendo, en ambos casos, por ponerse de acuerdo en la comunidad sobre si una pregunta debe existir y en qué modo.

En el caso 1 la pregunta fue cerrada porque era amplia y se planteó sin recabar el consenso de la comunidad.

En el caso 2 la pregunta fue cerrada porque vino otra y la sobrevoló. ¿Por qué no se apeló al consenso para mejorar la pregunta que se planteó primero.

Me pregunto si el **consenso** del que tanto he escuchado hablar tiene unos límites concretos y definidos o si es sólo un concepto abstracto, del cual podemos echar mano sólo en ciertas ocasiones.

Entonces, **el consenso, ¿qué es realmente?**

Comment: ¿podrías explicar que significa que "la pregunta fue sobrevolada"? No me es familiar dicha palabra (aparte del contexto que tiene que ver con los aviones).

Comment: @Shaz No necesariamente tienen que ser aviones, pueden ser [grifos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grifo), que son aves voladoras.

Comment: @ArtEze tienes razón, es mucho más genérico el término (no solo aviones), sin embargo creo que se entiende lo que quiero decir.

Comment: @Shaz _sobrevolar_ significa según la RAE: _"Volar por encima de alguien o de algo, como un lugar, una ciudad o un territorio."_ Es una acción que podría ser antonima del _consenso_, al menos como yo lo entiendo. De ahí mi pregunta, no sea que el consenso sea otra cosa.

Answer (score -2):

En el caso específico sobre sobre el significado del discurso de quienes utilizan el término "consenso" no es sencillo, sería útil tener a un especialista en [análisis del discurso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lisis_del_discurso).

Mientras llega uno, les comparto mi opinión "en caliente".

En síntesis, debe continuar la discusión de cada hilo en su hilo.

De forma extendida, una de las cosas a tener presente es que aquí muy pocas cosas van a ser calificadas como "[cosa juzgada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosa_juzgada)", es decir, que se han resuelto de forma definitiva y permanente por no existir forma de que proceda una solicitud de revisión. Por lo anterior y en un sentido amplio puede decirse que **casi todas las decisiones están sujetas a revisión**.

- Cuando algo no esté claro, solicitemos aclaración.
- Cuando no estemos conforme una decisión, de forma civilizada solicitemos la revisión de ser posible por miembros que no han participado en la decisión original.

Otra de las cosas a tener presente y por lo cual me parece que una pregunta como esta es pertinente, es que hay muy pocos hilos sobre las formas y estilos de lenguaje, por el momento sólo tengo presente [¿Cómo de estrictos debemos ser al editar diferentes variedades del español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/51/65). Sin embargo, por más hilos que tengamos al respecto por ser esta una comunidad abierta, el entendernos requiere de buena voluntad y de asumir que el otro también actúa con buena voluntad.

En esta pregunta se incluyen los enlaces a dos casos específicos, la aclaración, debería hacerse en cada uno, porque el uso de "consenso" en uno no implica que sea el mismo en el otro. Abordando esto de forma general y pensando en otros casos pasados o futuros, en cada caso el conocer el contexto específico y autor que ha usado el término "consenso" nos podría ayudar a tener certeza semántica de lo dicho.

Sin haber hecho un análisis, me voy atrevo compartir que en los casos que he leído me ha parecido que se ha usado "consenso" para hacer referencia a la [regla de la mayoría](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_de_la_mayor%C3%ADa) cuando ni siquiera eso está en efecto, pues en muchos casos lo que opera es cumplir con la cuota establecida de votos habiendo para ello reglas de la cantidad de votos requeridos por caso en los que el número de votos requeridos varía según los privilegios de los votantes.

Recordemos que los votantes pueden ser

- moderadores comunes, usuarios con +250 puntos de reputación
- moderadores con medallas doradas de etiqueta, usuarios con +1000 puntos en una etiqueta
- moderadores de la comunidad también denotados como moderadores ♦, ya sea Pro Tempore, electos, o empleados de Stack Exchange
- gerente de la comunidad.

Como se podrá ver no es nada sencillo dar una respuesta canónica al significado de "consenso" en este espacio por lo que mi recomendación es que pongamos en práctica la "aclaración de lo entendido", lo cual es,

> al recibir un mensaje de implicaciones importantes, antes de actuar, solicitemos confirmación de que hemos entendido el mensaje del emisor repitiendo este con nuestras propias palabras.

Bueno, pero ¿qué es consenso? Si somos estrictos y nos basamos en una fuente confiable como la Real Academia Española, de http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=consenso

> #### consenso.
>
> Del lat. consensus.
>
> 1. m. Acuerdo producido por consentimiento entre todos los miembros de un grupo o entre varios grupos.

Considerando que tenemos +40 000 miembros, aquí el consenso no es operativo.

Por cierto el artículo de Wikipedia sobre [consenso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consenso) está marcado que requiere referencias, pero coincide en decir que consenso es acuerdo de todos y que es distinto a la mayoría lo cual implica que una minoría disiente. Agrega otros términos como consenso social, consenso científico, consenso político

¿Será útil definir un consenso "stackoverflowrero"?

Comment: Los votantes pueden ser moderadores, pero en este caso no deberían, ya que es la decisión de uno solo el cierre o apertura.